# clearTimeout when wrapped in closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

**Updated**

HTML

```
<div class="notification-container" data-bind="foreach: notificationArray">
     <notification params="data: $data"></notification>
</div>
```

JS - using KnockoutJS to create an observable array of 'notification' messages.

```
appViewModel.notificationArray = ko.observableArray([
    { message : 'Test 1' },
    { message : 'test 2' }
]);
```

Using Knockout to create a notification component

```
ko.components.register('notification', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        var data = params.data;

        /* set the message to the data.message */
        this.message = data.message || null;

        /* removes the notification from the array */
        this.removeNotification = function() {
            appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data);
        };

        /* create timer to remove notification after 5s */
        /* need to wrap in closure so that inside of the setTimeout it can know about the data object needed to send to the remove() command */
        this.timer = function(obj, timeoutLength) {
            /* adding return statement per suggestion on Stack Overflow */
            return setTimeout(function() {
                appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(obj);
            }, timeoutLength);
        };

        this.timer(data, 5000);

       /* log will output function structure */
       /* clearTimeout will not work */
        this.hover = function() {
            console.log(this.timer);
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }

    },
    template: '<div class="notification show-notification" data-bind="event: { mouseover: hover, fastClick: hover }">'
        +'<div class="notifications-close clickable right" data-bind="fastClick: removeNotification"><span class="icon icon-x"></span></div>'
        +'<div class="notification-text" data-bind="text: message"></div>'
        +'</div>'
});
```

**Updating to reflect working solution**

JS

```
appViewModel.notificationArray = ko.observableArray([
    { message : 'Test 1' },
    { message : 'test 2' }
]);


ko.components.register('notification', {
    viewModel: function(params) {

        var data = params.data;

        this.message = data.message || null;
        this.timer = null;

        this.removeNotification = function() {
            appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data);
        };

        this.timer =  ( function(self) {
            return setTimeout(function() {
                self.removeNotification();
            }, 5000);
        })(this);

        this.hover = function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        };

        this.restart = function() {
            this.timer = ( function(self) {
                return setTimeout(function() {
                    self.removeNotification();
                }, 5000);
            })(this);
        }

    },
    template: '<div class="notification show-notification" data-bind="event: { mouseover: hover, fastClick: hover, mouseout: restart }">'
        +'<div class="notifications-close clickable right" data-bind="fastClick: removeNotification"><span class="icon icon-x"></span></div>'
        +'<div class="notification-text" data-bind="text: message"></div>'
        +'</div>'
});
```

Comment: Where are you attaching the hover handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't setting `this.timer` to the result of `setTimeout`. Perhaps you need `return setTimeout`?

Now for your 2nd problem. `this.hover` is invoked with `this` as something else. This has been solved in numerous other questions. One way is to use `var self = this` in the right scope for the correct `this` or my current preference is `this.hover = function() {...}.bind(this);`.

Comment: Unless your use case is more complicated than the example, there really isn't any point in the closure and you could just use `this.timer = setTimeout(...)`

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my OP to reflect your suggestion.  I may be implementing it wrong however as it does not in fact function any better than before.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you, I have added a section to my OP showing the final working code.  Can you explain to me though why this:
          
this.timer =  ( function(self) {
                return setTimeout(function() {
                    self.removeNotification();
                }, 5000);
            })(this);

Is different than:

this.timer =  function(self) {
                return setTimeout(function() {
                    self.removeNotification();
                }, 5000);
            };

this.timer(this);

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: this answer started before that accepted answer was posted. The issues identified are similar with slightly different solutions.*

1) You can replace the whole `this.timer =` statement with

```
var timerId =  setTimeout(function(){
    appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data), 5000);
    timerId = 0;  // timer finished
};
```

then timerId is in function scope of the anonomous function passed to setTimeout (a.k.a. "a closure") where it, and `data`, can both be seen.

2) The hover function can make use of closure as well.

```
this.hover = function() {
    console.log("timer " + timerId ? timerId : "finished");
    if( timerId)
        clearTimeout(timerId); 
}
```